# Can we make graphics on OS X and Linux directly with C just like we can on Windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, graphics

On Windows, we can just `#include <windows.h>` in C and do some graphical stuff. Do OS X and Linux (desktop) have such APIs for C?

Comment: You are looking for [X11](http://math.msu.su/~vvb/2course/Borisenko/CppProjects/GWindow/xintro.html)

Comment: What sort of *"graphical stuff"* do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, open a new windows and draw lines, circles, etc.

Comment: @AlterMann, that seems exactly what I want. But I am getting "Cannot Open Display" error. And that does not seem to happen often locally according to my google results. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: If you want to use X11 in any recent version of OSX, you will need to install `XQuartz`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am sure that I have installed it. It seems that the XOpenDisplay function is not working. Sometimes it tells me segmentation fault.

Comment: @AlterMann, I have solved it. I should run it from the X11 terminal, not the system terminal. But why so? How can I modify it so that it can start if I start it normally?

Comment: Aszune,  sorry I don't know,  I use gtk

Comment: Did you set the `DISPLAY` environment variable before starting any X programs? `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at SDL, which does what you ask, and can run fast on OSX, Linux and Windows.

It is available [here](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is [QT](http://www.qt.io/developers/)

It is really interesting why do you want write a desktop application with using с-language

Comment: OP is looking for native windows (like `windows. h`) and  there are tons of desktop applications using C

Comment: @AlterMann You can build a native application for each of OSs. http://doc.qt.io/QtSupportedPlatforms/index.html

Comment: Multiplatform doesn't mean native ;)